# Replace With Regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

can notepad++ replace using regex for this one:

[image: before replace]

[image: after replace]

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like so:

Find What: `\((\d+), \d+, ('.+?'), (\d+), ('[^']+').+\)`
Replace with: `\($1, $2, $3, $4\)`

Takes as input: `(35, 25, 'xxxx.com', 82, '2014-07-18', 3, '2013-07-18', 1, 1,...)` yields: `(35, 'xxxx.com', 82, '2014-07-18')`.

As an FYI, when posting code, please do not use images.

Comment: wow it works!! your one line codes save alot of my times! thank you so much! hell i just want to show the difference more strikingly.. what's their problem..

Comment: @YogaFishguts When dealing with code and especially text patterns, it is important that we have the same source as you do. Pasting images can lead to copy errors as well as it is time consuming ;).